# dynamic compilation failure due to spring-mobile plugin for grails

Tags: grails, dynamic-compilation, spring-mobile

I am using the spring mobile plugin 0.3 for grails and since using it in any controller, if I make any modification in that controller and refresh the application url in browser, the compilation fails with error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: LoginController.withMobileDevice() is applicable for argument types: (LoginController$_closure2_closure11) values: [LoginController$_closure2_closure11@2a5b68ea]
```

withMobileDevice is provided by the plugin..

is there any modification in config I can do to support dynamic compilation using this plugin and without restarting the server each time any modification in controller using the plugin is done..
Thanks